# Can't return correct error type for an Excel UDF

Tags: excel, error-handling, user-defined-functions, vba

I've written a fairly simple UDF in Excel, and now I'm adding error checking. Essentially it just returns the substring between two delimiters in a string. If either delimiter is not found, I want it to return an #N/A error (as something like MATCH would). I do this by

```
If (start_delim_pos = 0 Or end_delim_pos = 0) Then
    MYFUNCTION= CVErr(xlErrNA)
End If
```

But, I get a #VALUE error. No matter what I put in the `CVErr` function, I get a #VALUE error out.

Any ideas on what the problem might be, and how to get the desired error returned?

Comment: Call your function from a Sub in VBA, and if there's an error you'll get to debug it. UDF's don't break for debugging when called from a worksheet.  Or post the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you defined the return type of your UDF to be a `String`.

VBA does not convert `error variant` to string. When attempting to assign the returned string to an error, i.e.

> ```
> MYFUNCTION= CVErr(xlErrNA)
> ```

The UDF breaks with `type mismatch` and Excel displays `#VALUE!`.

If you want to allow your function to return either a string or an error code, make its return type `As Variant` (or simply omit it).

```
Function MYFUNCTION(...) As Variant
'                        ^^^^^^^^^^  Not As String
```